# Complex variable sum, difference

Tags: complex-numbers

I am reading through a text, about a question that concerns addition, difference of two complex variables.
I am confused as to why the calculation is different from mine.

Two complex numbers $z_1$ = 1 - i$\sqrt3$, $z_2$ = 3 + 4i.

The book concurs with me till stating that: |$z_1$| = 2, |$z_2$| = 5.

But, then it states that |$z_1$ + $z_2$| = $\sqrt(9 - (3 - \sqrt(3)^2)$ (= 3.2569), & difference is |$z_1$ - $z_2$| = $\sqrt(1 + (3 + \sqrt3)^2$ (= 4.8366).

My calculation states the below:

Sum of the two :
|$z_1$ + $z_2$| = $\sqrt(16 + (4-\sqrt3)^2)$ => $\sqrt(16 + (16 +3 -8\sqrt3))$

=> $\sqrt(35 -8\sqrt3))$ = 4.59821

Difference of the two :
|$z_1$ - $z_2$| = $\sqrt((-2)^2 + (-\sqrt3 -4)^2$ => $\sqrt(4 + (3 +16 +8\sqrt3)$

=> $\sqrt(23 +8\sqrt3)$ = 6.0709.

Comment: Your calculation of $|z_1+z_2|$ is correct, the book's value looks like $|z_1+iz_2|$ (and same thing for $|z_1-z_2|$). Either it is a typo in the book, or you have misread.

Comment: @MårtenW: I am not mistaken. But the book seems wild in its error.

Comment: Your own computations look correct to me, but the book is wrong here.